# Bing gives NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on my website

Tags: https, security-certificate, bing

I have added my site https://greymeter.com on Bing Webmaster. But when I search greymeter on bing.com, it gives https://www.greymeter.com as the result, and navigating to it, gives a crossed https with error `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`, and this message is displayed:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.greymeter.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

It works perfectly with google.com though. Can you please give me any idea, what I am missing, or what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing probably expects that if you give it the domain name example.com that it should use www.example.com instead. Because that is what many users would probably expect too.

But, your certificate is valid for greymeter.com,  api.greymeter.com and meta.greymeter.com but not for www.greymeter.com. Thus you get NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID which means that the hostname in the certificate does not match the name in the URL.